# Azure Function Dependency Injection - Using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable Inside FunctionsStartup

Tags: azure-functions

I've read a lot of posts on accessing IConfiguration inside Startup like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4577) and I've seen people building their own ConfigurationRoot, but for my simple scenario:

1. Access app settings from local.settings.json when developing locally
2. Access app settings and from Azure App Settings when running in production/cloud

Is it OK to use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable which meets both of those requirements?

Comment: Yes, the settings will be read as env var by default. It is from local.settings.json on local and it is from configuration settings on azure.

Comment: Any more problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Azure Function is based on Web App Sandbox, so it's env var is from Application Settings.

Have a look of Azure Function Basic of Web App Sandbox:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/functions-basics

This is the way to access the env var:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/environment-variables?tabs=csharp#accessing-environment-variables

This doc explains the local.settings.json is the app settings when azure function is running on local:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file

And this explains azure function app settings is in Configuration on azure:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings

**Original Answer:**

Yes, it is ok.

Azure Function reads settings from local.settings.json on local and reads settings from Configuration settings on Azure, both of them will be read as env var.

So you can simply use

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("yoursettingskey");
```

Comment: Can you add some supporting documentation?

Comment: @StringerBell I have update my answer, you can have a look.:)

Comment: I think the relevant part is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#use-application-settings) which says "The function app settings values can also be read in your code as environment variables." and later "When you develop a function app locally, you must maintain local copies of these values in the local.settings.json project file.". Thanks for finding the right docs!